# Is there a good program to play chess online in ubuntu?

Tags: software

I really missed playing chess with someone who know how to play, I am looking for a good program to play chess online from ubuntu computer.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Related question on Ask Ubuntu: [What's the best chess program for a beginner?](https://askubuntu.com/q/43479/301745) You could also check out the [highest voted 'chess' questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/chess?tab=Votes)

Comment: Did you mean a desktop program for Ubuntu, instead of a web site as per the answers?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On ubuntu, you can download Firefox, Chrome, or any other browser of your choice. From within that browser, go to lichess.org, chess.com, or chess24.com, create a free account, and play against others online.

Comment: Or xkcd: https://xkcd.com/934/

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Mine too. Also I think it is worth mentioning that lichess is free, open source and libre ([repository](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/)). You can play without any account. You don't have to register. It is a good things that you mention two others choices so people can compare and play with us on lichess :)

Comment: Or www.GameKnot.com

Answer (score 1):

With Winboard or Arena, you could play also in chess servers, like [FICS](https://www.freechess.org/) --free-- or ICC or several others that are listed in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_chess_servers) article on chess servers on Wikipedia.

Comment: He would be better using XBoard than WinBoard (which is a Windows port of XBoard)

Comment: @Ángel Yes you are right. I omit the right name for linux systems: XBoard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a lightweight CLI experience, and you have telnet enabled, try 'telnet freechess.org' on the command line.

Comment: OMG I tried it, hats off for the approach on ASCII art, but it's very difficult for me to get used to that board.